# How to draw around a texture in LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx, textures

I'm making a game in libgdx where the main character has a light on him and where the light doesn't reach it should be dark, I'm using the setBlendFunction from SpriteBash to emulate the light. My problem is I don't know how I can make all around the light texture dark, I could size the light texture to fit the whole screen but that would be sloppy and an inconveniente in code. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks you.

Here is a picture of the game showing my problem

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically done with a FrameBuffer.

You want to instantiate and recreate as necessary in the `resize()` method so it always matches the size of the screen/window. In `resize()`:

```
if (frameBuffer != null && (frameBuffer.getWidth() != width || frameBuffer.getHeight() != height)){
    frameBuffer.dispose();
    frameBuffer = null;
}
if (frameBuffer == null){
    try {
        frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, width, height, false);
    } catch (GdxRuntimeException e){ // device doesn't support 8888
        frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGB565, width, height, false);
    }
}
```

And in `render()`, before drawing anything in your game, you first draw the shadow map on the frameBuffer:

```
frameBuffer.begin();
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(/* ... */); // This will be your ambient color, a dark color, like gray
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined); // same camera as your game scene
spriteBatch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE); //additive blending
spriteBatch.begin();

// draw light sprites, such as a white circle where your character is standing

spriteBatch.end();
frameBuffer.end();
```

Then draw your game scene normally. Don't forget to change your blend function back to what you normally use (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA by default) before drawing that. And finally, draw the shadow map over the game:

```
// Use identity matrix so you don't have to worry about lining up the frame buffer texture
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(spriteBatch.getProjectionMatrix().idt());

// Set multiplicative blending for shadows
spriteBatch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ZERO, GL20.GL_SRC_COLOR); 

spriteBatch.begin();
spriteBatch.draw(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture(), -1, 1, 2, -2); //dimensions for full screen with identity matrix
spriteBatch.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont't you use [Box2dlight](https://github.com/libgdx/box2dlights) for your requirement. In my opinion you can use shader for lighting but the effect that you want that can only be achieved by using box2d body and box2dlight.

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor{

    SpriteBatch batch;
    OrthographicCamera cam;

    RayHandler rayHandler;
    World world;
    Texture texture;
    PointLight box2d;

    Box2DDebugRenderer renderer;
    Vector3 vector3;
    Array<Body> bodies;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        Pixmap pixmap=new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        pixmap.fillRectangle(0,0, pixmap.getWidth(), pixmap.getHeight());

        world=new World(new Vector2(0,-9.8f),false);
        rayHandler=new RayHandler(world);

        renderer=new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        bodies=new Array<>();
        vector3=new Vector3();

        batch=new SpriteBatch();
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(true,40,64);

        texture=new Texture(pixmap);
        rayHandler.setAmbientLight(0,0,0,.5f);

        box2d=new PointLight(rayHandler, 100, new Color(1,1,1,1), 25, 10, 10);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);


        {
            BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
            bodyDef.position.set(20, 10);
            bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;

            PolygonShape p = new PolygonShape();
            p.setAsBox(8, 1.5f);

            FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
            fixtureDef.shape = p;

            Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
            body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

            Sprite sprite=new Sprite(texture);
            sprite.setSize(8*2,1.5f*2);
            body.setUserData(sprite);
        }

        {
            BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
            bodyDef.position.set(20, 40);
            bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;

            PolygonShape p = new PolygonShape();
            p.setAsBox(8, 1.5f);

            FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
            fixtureDef.shape = p;

            Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
            body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

            Sprite sprite=new Sprite(texture);
            sprite.setSize(8*2,1.5f*2);

            body.setUserData(sprite);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);

        world.step(1/60f,4,6);

        renderer.render(world,cam.combined);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        batch.begin();
        world.getBodies(bodies);

        for (Body body:bodies){
            Sprite sprite=(Sprite) body.getUserData();
            sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x-sprite.getWidth()/2,body.getPosition().y-sprite.getHeight()/2);
            sprite.draw(batch);
        }

        batch.draw(texture,100,100);
        batch.end();

        rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(cam);
        rayHandler.updateAndRender();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        rayHandler.dispose();   
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {

        vector3.set(screenX,screenY,0);
        Vector3 v=cam.unproject(vector3);
        box2d.setPosition(v.x,v.y);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT IS :

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to avoid having box2d.

Comment: your requirement can easily fulfil using box2d, box2d is not too bad if you play with physics body in proper way.

Comment: I agree, but for now I'm going the other route. Thank you for the answer.